# gnome-shell-extension app not working in wayland but works on xorg

Tags: nvidia, gnome, xorg, 22.04

I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 then I switched to Wayland. But now I'm having issues using GNOME extensions I already had. I used to use the chrome extension to manage the extensions but it doesn't work (I can't enable the extensions). I also installed gnome-shell-extension-manager but it doesn't open.

I musing GNOME Shell 42.1.
I have an NVIDIA card GTX 1070 and I'm using NVIDIA driver 510.

**Edit:**

The issue seems to be linked to Nvidia driver 510 see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1965563

Comment: there is a log on this [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1965563), the work around is to enable the extension you want in x11, the changes will crossover to wayland; however, you can't alter or turn them off/on in wayland.

Comment: I ended up with your solution. But after that I observed many bugs related to wayland with nvidia like when putting my computer to sleep or dual monitor. So I switched back to x11

Comment: Is gnome-shell-extension app the same that gets launched when running `gnome-extensions-app` from terminal? If so, adding `export __EGL_VENDOR_LIBRARY_FILENAMES=/usr/share/glvnd/egl_vendor.d/50_mesa.json` to `~/.profile` and rebooting fixed it for me (it's mentioned in the link you posted).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it in this way:
install extension manager:

> sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager

Press the start button and search for the extension manager. Then turn the extension on:
[image]

Comment: I can't even open gnome-shell-extension-manager

Comment: Did you try with gnome-shell-extension?

Comment: unfortunately. It's a know issue from I found

Comment: I could, now  cannot open it, either in power, apps, or from terminal. it could be that I am on wayland not xorg. extensions are still working though.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** It works now with the new NVIDIA driver version **515.65.01**

So just install the new driver:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515
```

Comment: In fact I have `nvidia-driver-515/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 515.65.01-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed] `

and still get this error
"Gdk-Message: 20:34:54.008: Error reading events from display: Protocol error" when running the extension manager. It does not open.